# ASP.NET Webmethod always Returns 401

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, ajax

Getting sick with asp.net permission madness...
This time, I Just cant AJAX-CALL any kind of webmethod or i just get:

```
{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

Code:

```
<WebMethod(True)> _
    Public Function Login(ByVal usuario As String, ByVal senha As String) As Boolean
        [lots of validations]
        If (con.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

JQUERY CALL:

```
$("#btnEnviar").click(function() {
            $('#login').hide();
            $('#ajaxLoader').fadeIn();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Login.aspx/Login",
                data: "{'usuario':'" + $('#txtUsuario').val() + "','senha':'" + $('#txtSenha').val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    var msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
                    if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                        return msg.d;
                    else
                        return msg;
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg.UsuarioValido == '1') {
                        top.location = "Home.aspx"
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#ajaxLoader').hide();
                        $('#login').fadeIn();
                    }
                }
        });
```

*THERE ARE SOME MISTAKES ON THE SUCCESS STUFF I KNOW. THATS NOT THE PROBLEM FOR NOW.*
Firebug Console always return 401 Unauthorized when i Try an ajax call.

Anyone?

Comment: what auth have you got setup in the web config?

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="Login" path="/" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Home.aspx">
      </forms>
    </authentication>

Comment: I assume you issue the authentication key to the client where you have the [lots of validations] placeholder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Webmethod Should be shared (vb) / static (C#) if you are getting ERROR 500, mark your method as Shared/Static and you are done.
2. About Error 401: If you are using forms authentication remember to allow anonymous access to your login page by doing this on your web.config:

   ```
   <location path="Login.aspx">
     <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
       </authorization>
     </system.web>
   </location>
   ```

Comment: I forgot the 'static' keyword and got 401 that I didn't understand.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These steps fixed the problem for me.

1) Add the below code in web.config

```
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
     <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

2) In ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs, change as below

**From:**  settings.AutoRedirectMode =RedirectMode.Permanent;

**To:**  settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;

3) In the ajax call, use the resolveurl method,
  **From:**  'userForm.aspx/getAllUsers'

**To:**  '<%= ResolveUrl("userForm.aspx/getAllUsers") %>'

So that the final jQuery code looks like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("userForm.aspx/getAllUsers") %>',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
      source.localdata = data.d;
    },
    error: function (err) {
      alert('Error: ' + err);
    }
  })
```

Please refer the below link for more information.
https://forums.asp.net/t/1975897.aspx?jquery+ajax+calls+to+asp+net+web+methods+authentication+error+